AWS Lambda (via Terraform) is Unable To Pull Image from a Replicated ECR
I have a private ECR Repository in ap-south-1, that is replicated to us-west-1. The replication is done correctly, and was done through CLI before; I can see the images being synced and was able to pull locally as well.
When I create an AWS Lambda function using this image_uri of us-west-1, it fails with the below error:
creating Lambda Function (my_sample_tmp): operation error Lambda: CreateFunction, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 310e56ea-e5f7-4f50-a9e5-fcf4555c55f5, InvalidParameterValueException: Source image 12345678910.dkr.ecr.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-repo:2-my-tag is not valid. Provide a valid source image.
The AWS Lambda code for Terraform is
  count         = length(keys(var.app_clients_config))
  function_name = "${var.app_name}_${var.server_name}_${var.app_environment}_${element(keys(var.app_clients_config), count.index)}"
  description   = "c360 Data Beacon function to process insights & alerts"
  timeout       = 50 # seconds
  image_uri     = "${var.aws_account_id}.dkr.ecr.${var.aws_region}.amazonaws.com/${var.aws_registry_image_name}:${var.app_data_beacon_version}"
  package_type  = "Image"

  role = var.aws_iam_role_lambda_exec_role_arn
  environment {
    variables = {
      ENVIRONMENT = var.app_environment,
      CLIENT      = element(keys(var.app_clients_config), count.index)
    }
  }
}

The IAM policy document is
  statement {
    sid    = "AllowInvokingLambdas"
    effect = "Allow"

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:lambda:*:*:function:*"
    ]

    actions = [
      "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    ]
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "AllowECRAccessForLambda"
    effect = "Allow"

    resources = ["*"]

    actions = [
      "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
      "ecr:BatchGetImage",
      "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
      "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
      "ecr:ListImages"
    ]
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "AllowECRAuthTokenForLambda"
    effect = "Allow"

    resources = ["*"]

    actions = [
      "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken"
    ]
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "AllowWritingLogs"
    effect = "Allow"

    resources = [
      "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/*:*"
    ]

    actions = [
      "logs:CreateLogStream",
      "logs:PutLogEvents",
    ]
  }

  statement {
    sid    = "AccessSecrets"
    effect = "Allow"

    resources = [
      "*"
    ]

    actions = [
      "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
      "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
    ]
  }

}```


**It works well from the UI, but not via Terraform**


Is the ECR public or private?

The ECR Repo is a private one which is replicated across 2 zones.

According to the documentation:

For a function in the same account as the container image in Amazon ECR, you can add ecr:BatchGetImage and ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer permissions to your Amazon ECR repository policy. The following example shows the minimum policy:

{
    "Sid": "LambdaECRImageRetrievalPolicy",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": [
      "ecr:BatchGetImage",
      "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
    ]
}

When you do it in the UI they update the repository's Policy for you.
Can you confirm that your ECR repository has this Poilcy?

Yes, I tried this both the source and replicated repository. Same issue.
